# MassTransit sends a durable message when a non durable one is configured

Tags: masstransit

I'm trying to send a message to an queue. The queue exists already and is configured as non durable. Here's my code:

```
ServiceBus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(sbc =>
            {
                sbc.PurgeOnStartup = true;
                sbc.Durable = false;
                sbc.Exclusive = false;

                sbc.Host(new Uri($"rabbitmq://{RabbitMqHost}"), cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.ConfigureRabbitMq();
                });
            });

ServiceBus.Request(
                        new Uri(serviceUri),
                        new EngineStartingMessage() { Version = ApplicationConfig.SystemVersion },
                        rCfg =>
                        {
                            rCfg.Durable = false;
                            rCfg.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
                            rCfg.Handle<EngineStartingResponse>(async hContext =>
                            {
                                //Response handling
                            });
                        });
```

As you can see Durable is set to false. On ServiceBus.Request I get the following exception:

> The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by
>   Peer, code=406, text="PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'durable'
>   for exchange 'QUEUENAMEHERE' in vhost '/': received 'true' but current
>   is 'false'", classId=40, methodId=10, cause=

Any ideas why the message is still sent as durable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Durable flag only specifies that the particular request message should not be persisted to disk.

If you want to fix this, add `?durable=false` to the serviceUri, to match what's being specified at the receive endpoint which handles the request.

Comment: Thank you @Chris it helped but now I get a similar exception for - The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=406, text="PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'auto_delete' for exchange 'entityservice_STAGING5_engine_control_queue' in vhost '/': received 'false' but current is 'true'", classId=40, methodId=10, cause=

Comment: Anyway I can overwrite it as well? I tried specifying auto_delete = true and autodelete = true in the endpoint url like this '?durable=false&autodelete=true' but it didn't help.

Comment: Never mind, I'm being dump, autodelete = true helped